# Issue with subscribe on observable

Tags: angular, angular7

I have following code as part of service:

```
return this.httpClient.get<Country[]>('http://localhost:8080/countries');
```

It passes unit test with mocked values.
However when used in ngOnInit() function it doesn't assign relevant values to a variable.

```
this.supportedCountriesFetcherService.fetchSupportedCountries().subscribe((data) => (this.supportedCountries = data));
```

I have tested with postman and localhost returns relevant json.
If I were to log data of subscribe instead of assigning it there wouldn't be returned data logged (in fact either blank log would be added or none at all).

How can I resolve this issue?

Edit:

Service related code (without interfaces):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SupportedCountriesFetcherService {

  public fetchSupportedCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
     return this.httpClient.get<Country[]>('http://localhost:8080/countries');
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Component related code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Country, SupportedCountriesFetcherService } from 'src/app/services/supported-countries-fetcher.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-form',
  templateUrl: './input-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-form.component.css']
})
export class InputFormComponent implements OnInit {

  private supportedCountries: Country[];

  constructor(private supportedCountriesFetcherService: SupportedCountriesFetcherService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.supportedCountriesFetcherService.fetchSupportedCountries()
     .subscribe((data) => this.supportedCountries = data, (error) => console.log(error));
   }

}
```

Comment: So your problem is inside of unittest?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat no, the problem appears in component to which service is imported

Comment: Can you open develoiper console and check network?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat - with network opened there doesn't seem to be any relevant request (none of URLs matches what is put in service).

Comment: Can you please publish full source of your service and component?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I have updated post with related code

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an error on the http request.
Try changing your subscription to add an error handler, like this:

```
this.supportedCountriesFetcherService.fetchSupportedCountries()
  .subscribe(
     (data) => this.supportedCountries = data,
     (err) => console.error(err);
  );
```

and you should see the error.

I'm assuming that your Angular app is running on port 4200, which means that  unless you're using a proxy, you're probably getting a CORS error.

If that's the case, the easiest thing to do for development purposes is to set up a proxy server.

You can read the official docs for setting up the webpack dev server proxy at https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately I have already configured CORS, I tried logging error however any log doesn't appear (or blank log is added).